# c# Else not working as expected

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

```
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int current = 0;
        int noa = 0;
        while (current != 6) {
            current =r.Next(1,7);
                noa += 1;
                Console.WriteLine(current + " has been rolled.");
        }

        if (noa >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You were unlucky and it took you "+ noa + " times to roll a 6!");
        }
        if (noa <= 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You were quite lucky and it took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

}
So problem occurs when noa(number of attempts) is higher than 10 and what it shows is:

> 2 has been rolled.
>   5 has been rolled.
>   4 has been rolled.
>   5 has been rolled.
>   5 has been rolled.
>   1 has been rolled.
>   2 has been rolled.
>   1 has been rolled.
>   3 has been rolled.
>   4 has been rolled.
>   6 has been rolled.
>   You were unlucky and it took you 11times to roll a 6!
>   It took you 11 times to roll a 6!

And what I dont want to happen is console writing that second line "It took you 11 times to roll a 6!".
Why is this happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make it `elseif`

```
if (noa >= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You were unlucky and it took you "+ noa + " times to roll a 6!");
}
else if (noa <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You were quite lucky and it took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
}
```

**Edit**
Agreed with @Kalmino, the cause of the problem is all the conditions are treated together in one conditional branching with `if... elseif... else` .

Comment: @tagito the way you have it (as opposed to this) is treating the >= 10 and the next if/else as two separate statements.  The else if that CarbineCoder put in joins all 3 of them so it evaluates them together instead of checking the >= 10 and THEN checking <= 5 or Else.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand it, but what if I need 4 ifs? will i be able to do it by " if; else if; else if; else;?

Comment: you just have to add one more `else if` before the last `else` statement

Answer (score 3):

Because of this

```
if (noa <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You were quite lucky and it took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It took you " + noa + " times to roll a 6!");
}
```

What happens if `noa>5`?